# Grouping products in magento

Tags: php, magento, product, magento-1.8

I want to group products in magento. All I want is that a product which contain two or more sub products and i want to display the main product only. Can I do this in anyway? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the visibility of the sub products to "not visible" and let the main product visible in both catalog and search. don't forget reindexing and cache cleaning after that !

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was helpful for me. And I have another doubt that can I group products?